# loader не появляется в IE11 до отправки ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, что может мешать отображению лоадера перед отправкой ajax запроса(beforeSend) в IE11. В Других браузерах работает стабильно.

```
     $.ajax({
         url: path,
         datatype: "json",
         cache: false,
         async: true,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         method: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify({ // ....  }),
         beforeSend: function () {
             $("#shadow").show();
             $("#loader").show();
             $("#filter").prop('disabled', true);
         },
         complete: function () {
             $("#loader").hide();
             $("#filter").prop('disabled', false);
             $("#shadow").hide();
         },
         success: function (data) {
            // ....
         }
```

CSS loader:

```css
#Loader {
    display: none;
}

.holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;  
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.preloader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    animation: rotatePreloader 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes rotatePreloader {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateZ(-360deg);
    }
}

.preloader div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.preloader div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.preloader div:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    animation: rotateCircle1 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 9;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle1 {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(36deg);
    }
    7% {
      transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    57% {
      transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotateZ(36deg);
    animation: rotateCircle2 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 8;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle2 {
    5% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    5.0001% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    12% {
      transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
    }
    62% {
      transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotateZ(72deg);
    animation: rotateCircle3 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 7;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle3 {
    10% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    10.0002% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
    }
    17% {
      transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
    }
    67% {
      transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotateZ(108deg);
    animation: rotateCircle4 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 6;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle4 {
    15% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    15.0003% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
    }
    22% {
      transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
    }
    72% {
      transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotateZ(144deg);
    animation: rotateCircle5 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 5;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle5 {
    20% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    20.0004% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
    }
    27% {
      transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
    }
    77% {
      transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    animation: rotateCircle6 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 4;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle6 {
    25% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25.0005% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
    }
    32% {
      transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
    }
    82% {
      transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(7) {
    transform: rotateZ(216deg);
    animation: rotateCircle7 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle7 {
    30% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    30.0006% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
    }
    37% {
      transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
    }
    87% {
      transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(8) {
    transform: rotateZ(252deg);
    animation: rotateCircle8 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle8 {
    35% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.0007% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
    }
    42% {
      transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
    }
    92% {
      transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(9) {
    transform: rotateZ(288deg);
    animation: rotateCircle9 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle9 {
    40% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    40.0008% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
    }
    47% {
      transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
    }
    97% {
      transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(10) {
    transform: rotateZ(324deg);
    animation: rotateCircle10 2s infinite linear;
    z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle10 {
    45% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    45.0009% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
    }
    52% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    }
    102% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div id="loader">
    <div  class="holder">
        <div class="preloader">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Стили `#loader`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, добавил css. Видимо есть еще ошибка, но я ее не вижу.

Comment: Укажите версию IE

Comment: Сам по себе лоадер работает. Значит, дело в чем-то другом. Что такое `$("#shadow")`? Поставьте `console.log()` в метод `beforeSend`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, метод отрабатывает, в консоль выводит. $("#shadow") это растянутый блок, я уже и без него пробовал)

Comment: Значит ошибка где-то в другом месте, а не в приведенном коде.

Comment: У меня отображается лоадер в ie11.